# Google Analytics Include IP specific view

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up 3 views in Analytics

1. Standard view
2. An 'Exclude IP' view which filters *out* IP's from several internal IP addresses, using an individual Exclude filter for each IP address
3. An 'Include IP' view, which I am trying to use to include traffic *only* from several IP addresses.

The logic behind a view dedicated to internal IP addresses is as the site in question processes orders over the phone on behalf of customers through the website, which we want to track separately.

I have created 3 filters on my Include IP view, each with an `Include IP 123.456.789` but it's not actually showing any traffic at all.

How do I create a view to show traffic *only* from several specific IP addresses, and no other traffic?

Comment: First you make sure that you do not use the anonymize IP feature in GA, because that sets the last three number in a ipv4 IP address to zero before a filter kicks in. Apart from that an include filter with a regular expression should work fine. Plus this is not really on topic.

Comment: No it's not set to anonymise, but it's still not working. Plus, S.O. having a 'Google-analytics' tag dedicated for this topic suggests this is on topic.

Comment: This is not code related, thus off topic.  SO is not about configuration issues in SAAS interfaces, it's about programming problems. You can think this is dumb (frankly I do, sometimes) but it's there (in the help center, also discussed on the meta site).